# Defining selected tab by url in jQuery tab script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define which search type they want to use. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #**type**/***query***/. If #**type** is in the URL the tab that corresponds to that type appears selected. However, If a query is also in the url (#**type**/***query***/) the tab isn't selected. With my code below, how can I make it so it will ignore everything after /**query**/? I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe.

My jQuery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        url = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        $('#type_' + url).click();
    } else {
        $('#type_search').click();
    }
    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    var textlength = $('#query').val().length;
    if (textlength <= 0) {
        $('#query').focus();
    } else {
        $('#query').blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you do a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: If the url is `http://www.example.com/#type/query/someOtherString` you want the script to treat it as if it were `http://www.example.com/#type/query/`? Or do you want strip out everything following the `#type/`, treating it as if it were: `http://www.example.com/#type/`?

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to do a substring for the URL and detect where the first `/` is?

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what exactly you're trying to do. You're saying that you want `$('#type_' + url).click();` to use the shortened `#type` description? So that `url` would not have the full path used in the GET Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly clumsy way I came up with is:

```
$('a').each(
    function(){
        var url = this.href;
        var hashAt = url.indexOf('#');
        var nextSlashAt = url.indexOf('/',hashAt);
        var url = url.substring(0,nextSlashAt);
        var tab = url.substring(hashAt);
        $(this).text(url + " (" + tab + ").");
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FjxKr/).

Obviously rather than iterating through the `a` elements, you'll want to assign the `url` variable to the `window.location;`, but from then on it should be easily adapted to your needs, I think.

---

References:

- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Probably, yes. As a starting point work out what part(s) of this solution you need, and strip out the bits you don't. To make it more simple? You'd have to show a live demo so's I can see what's going on, which would involve (probably) a contrived [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) (since the `window.location` wouldn't be what you'd want, there); or a live demo on a site you control.

Comment: Well, you could `split()` on the `#` and search for the first `/`. http://jsfiddle.net/FjxKr/1/

Comment: *Oooh*, **+1** for the brevity @Jared! =)

Comment: It will even work if a url is simply `#type/query/etc` (instead of  `http://www.example.com/#type/query/etc`). I couldn't figure out how to get it on one line, though.